# ConvertToHTML converting wrong

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run the following command and return it through HTML:

`[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($env:computerName).Hostname`

This returns my computer name, however if I try to export it to HTML, using ConvertTo-HTML I retrieve an arbatory value of "* 27":

`[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($env:computerName).Hostname | ConvertTo-Html`

Result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
</head><body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>*</th></tr>
<tr><td>27</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

I'd expect the result to be the output of the first command, which is my actual PC name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as [documented: property supplied by the pipeline is `InputObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/ConvertTo-Html):

> **-InputObject**
>
> … To create a table of the individual objects, use the pipeline
> operator to pipe the objects to `ConvertTo-Html`.

When you submit multiple objects to `ConvertTo-Html`, PowerShell creates the **table** (or list) **based on the properties of the first object that you submit**.

You piped a string; hence, the table shows the only string property, its length (the number 27 in your output).

Try

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($env:computerName) |
    ConvertTo-HTML -Property HostName
```